# proving that local sequence alignment can be done in linear space

Tags: dynamic-programming, subsequences, bioinformatics

according to the [Smith-Waterman setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm), I have 2 string sequences S and T, and I want to identify their respective subsequences $\alpha$ and $\beta$ whose global alignment have maximum score over all pairs of subsequences. As usual, the scoring system is a substitution matrix and a gap-scoring scheme. However, **I want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with linear space**.

I know how to find the terminating point $(i^*, j^*)$ of the subsequences - I'm doing `DP` (dynamic programming) from the top-left, while throwing away negative scores.  The values in each row can be computed in a
row wise fashion and the algorithm must store values for only two rows at a time = linear space. I'll maintain the best score I saw and call it `opt`, and the indexes of `opt` would be $(i^*, j^*)$.

**But now how do I find the starting point $(i', j')$?** I thought about doing `DP` starting from $(i^*, j^*)$ going to the top-left corner, and stop when I reach the `opt` score from before. But how do I prove that I'll find a point with the `opt` score?

once I prove that, I just use `Hirschberg` from $(i^*, j^*)$ to $(i', j')$ and I'm done.

Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia claims that Myers and Miller optimized the space complexity from $O(mn)$ to $O(n)$.  Have you tried looking at their paper?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm#History